# Kids in a post-apocalyptic world playing a hockey-like game

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

I've been trying to remember the name of a movie I saw once, when I was younger - maybe early 1990s. The movie takes place in a post-apocalyptic world. Water is rationed and the world is basically a desert. All the water in the world has been locked up in a building/bunker.

I remember there being some, I think kids, playing a hockey-like game with round balls. One of them finds a new ball the glows or something, in the end it turns out to be a comet.

I know it sounds weird, maybe I made it up and just think I watched it when I was a kid. It may well have been a made-for-TV movie. Anyone remember anything like this that can help describe it better than me? I'm looking for the title of the movie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be [Solarbabies](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091981/).

While searching for it, I also found [Tank Girl](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114614/) that is on a similar topic and seems interesting:

> **Storyline**
>
> In a future in which most water has disappeared from the Earth, we find a group of children, mostly teenagers, who are living at an orphanage, run by the despotic rulers of the new Earth. The group in question plays a hockey based game on roller skates and is quite good. It has given them a unity that transcends the attempts to bring them to heel by the government. Finding an orb of special power, they find it has unusual effects on them. They escape from the orphanage (on skates) and try to cross the wasteland looking for a place they can live free as the stormtroopers search for them and the orb.

Comment: Which had the actors who played Michael and Star in "Lost Boys" which in turn was a marketing point because the film was 'a tad' on the weak side.

Comment: It is `Solarbabies`. How did you find it, I've searched IMDB many times. `Tank Girl` is a fun movie to, I remember watching that as a kid as well.

Comment: Avio, please add a synopsis of the movie and **why** this is the answer to the question.

Comment: @Justin808, I don't know, I just searched for what you said. Look, I've found in my browser history what I've searched for: `apocalyptic movie kid ball glow comet` :)